# Pagination not working in Vuejs2

Tags: pagination, vuejs2

I'm trying to make pagination in Vuejs 2 project
i write a code like in this demo
https://jsfiddle.net/os7hp1cy/48/

it's work fine in Vuejs 1 (vue-1.0.23)
however when i use this code with Vuejs 2 (vue@2.4.2) it's show me this error message :

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "paginate" is not defined on the instance 

but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data 

properties in the data option.

(found in <Root>)
```

how i can fix that error
thanks

Comment: Provide also jsfiddle with your Vuejs 2 implementation. Otherwise it will be hard to help you since nobody can see the exact code with the problem you want to be fixed.

Comment: I just change vuejs 1 to vuejs 2 in the same code but it's not working , i do some search and to solve this problem i need to create filter function in computed function but i don't know  how ??

Comment: You have compute in your example https://jsfiddle.net/os7hp1cy/48/.   totalPages is computed. Just add another one. Computed are awesome - they cached and recalculated only when the data it depends on changes. Check the documentation - it's very clear: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Answer (score 0):

In your code have this line:

```
v-for="user in users | filterBy searchKey | paginate"
```

And all filters are removed in vue2 so your code won't work https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Filters

Moreover, you should not mount vue to `body`:

```
[Vue warn]: Do not mount Vue to <html> or <body> - mount to normal elements instead.
```

You can check my working code: https://jsfiddle.net/os7hp1cy/187/

Comment: your jsfiddle doesn't have pagination

Answer (score 0):

I've forked @imcvampire's code and make a working version for Vue 2 due to this filter migration https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Filters-Outside-Text-Interpolations-removed.

paginate method is moved to computed:

```
paginate: function() {
        if (!this.users || this.users.length != this.users.length) {
            return
        }
        this.resultCount = this.users.length
        if (this.currentPage >= this.totalPages) {
          this.currentPage = this.totalPages
        }
        var index = this.currentPage * this.itemsPerPage - this.itemsPerPage
        return this.users.slice(index, index + this.itemsPerPage)
    }
```

WARNING: I didn't apply the text filter, just the pagination first.

https://jsfiddle.net/c1ghkw2p/